# Laravel Permission de Spatie y políticas directas con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, spatie

Estoy utilizando Spatie para controlar los permisos de mi aplicación, por ejemplo cada módulo tengo ver,crear, actualizar y eliminar y hasta ahí bien, ahora bien, quiero implementar Políticas para evitar que un usuario pueda modificar modelos que no le pertenecen. Creo que seguí bien la documentación pero no sé si entra en conflicto con Spatie.

En el modelo tengo:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Estudiante extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    .....
}
```

En la política tengo:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Estudiante;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class EstudiantePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


 public function view(User $user, Estudiante $estudiante)
    {
        //solo de prueba
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Y en el AuthServiceProvider tengo

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    ...
    protected $policies = [
        Estudiante::class => EstudiantePolicy::class,
    ];
    
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::before(function ($user, $ability){
            return $user->account == "SuperAdmin" ?? null;
        });
    }       

}
```

Con Spatie reviso si tiene autorizado esa operación CRUD y funciona perfectamente.

```
$this->authorize('ver-ficha-estudiante')
```

Y para validar la política desde el controlador.

```
public function edit(Estudiante $estudiante)
{
    //Tambien he probado con $user->can('view', $estudiante)
    if($this->authorize('update', $estudiante)){
        echo "bien";
    }
}
```

Y en las rutas tengo

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ["auth"]], function()
{
    Route::resource("ficha_estudiantes", FichaEstudianteController::class);

});
```

Al parecer nunca se llama a la política porque ni retornando siempre true funciona y ya la tengo registrada.

Cualquier ayuda les agradezco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema estaba en la puerta para determinar si era SuperAdmin.El operador de coalescencia nulo no tiene sentido en este caso y por ende la correccion seria esta:

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
            if ($user->hasRole('SuperAdmin')) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Si el usuario tiene el rol SuperAdmin se retorna true y no se vuelve a realizar las verificaciones de permiso. **Es importante NO devolver false en caso contrario**

Answer (score 0):

También es importante inyectar las dependencias de los métodos del Policy.

Estuve horas hasta darme cuenta que si no inyectas todas las dependencias que te requieren los métodos de ViewAny o View, estos no lo avisan bien sino que directamente lanzan la excepción de AuthorizationException.